# Print a data.frame to a file when one of the data.frame elements is a list in R

Tags: r

I'm a biologist trying to learn R programming and this is my first question on stackoverflow.  I've been trying to find the answer to this question but keep hitting dead ends.  I have a data.frame in R that contains two elements.  The first element is a character vector of human gene ids and the second element is a list containing scores for each gene

```
head(results)
gene_id                                                            Score
1    A1BG        3.2828283, 0.2378641, NA, 3.1857143, 9.6956522, 3.0759162
2   A2BP1            0.6417112, 0.6772069, 0.8581688, 1.9923954, 1.5723270
3     A2M                 2.826087, 1.115974, 4.392523, 3.165816, 1.422764
4  A4GALT            1.5883459, 1.9366197, 5.5967742, 0.8864038, 3.1920200
5   A4GNT 7.3592233, 1.3846154, 0.6046638, 4.7267081, 0.4980926, 3.4800000
6    AAA1            0.3452148, 0.9479344, 0.8114478, 6.0000000, 1.0670927
sapply(results, class)
gene_id       Score 
"character"      "list"
```

I would like to print this data.frame to a file so that each line of the file looks something like this:

```
A1BG        3.2828283, 0.2378641, NA, 3.1857143, 9.6956522, 3.0759162
```

I tried this but it obviously didn't work because of the presence of a list in the data.frame:

```
> lapply(results, write, "results.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

please note that the list cannot be coerced into a data.frame because each gene does not have the same number of scores associated with it i.e. some genes have 6 scores, some have 4 etc...

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can coerce your Score column as a string , and then store your data.frame using `write.table`:

```
 dat$score <- sapply(dat$score,paste,collapse=',')
```

#### Example:

```
dat <- 
  data.frame(id=1:3,score=I(list(1,1:2,1:3)))
dat$score <- 
  sapply(dat$score,paste,collapse=',')
write.table(dat,row.names=F)

# "id" "score"
#   1 "1"
#   2 "1,2"
#   3 "1,2,3"
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!  I really appreciate it.